# Categories and subcategories in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem. I've create a model for Categories, and Posts. In my project I used a categories->subcategories model. When I finished, createsuperuser and login in to the Admin Panel I show a Fields 'Category' and 'Posts'. When I want to add a new category as a parent, after I need to add children. I added 1 record 'Biznes' and Child 'Własna Firma'. I clicked add next and for that moment the Admin Panel thinking, thinking and not respond. I can't add Post, delete or Edit Category. Here is my
 **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Kategoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,verbose_name='Adres SEO')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)
        verbose_name = 'Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        full_path = [self.name]
        k = self.parent

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.name)
            k = k.parent

        return ' / '.join(full_path[::-1])

class Firma(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, verbose_name='Użytkownik', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Nazwa firmy')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='Adres SEO')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Kategoria', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Kategoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Opis')
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Szablon')
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Firma'
        verbose_name_plural='Firmy'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_cat_list(self):
        k = self.category
        breadcrumb = ["dummy"]
        while k is not None:
            breadcrumb.append(k.slug)
            k = k.parent

        for i in range(len(breadcrumb)-1):
            breadcrumb[i] = '/'.join(breadcrumb[-1:i-1:-1])
        return breadcrumb[-1:0:-1]
```

and **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Kategoria, Firma

class KategoriaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug' :('name',)}

admin.site.register(Kategoria, KategoriaAdmin)
admin.site.register(Firma)
```

EDIT:
When I use debugger I received a log:

```
(myvenv) λ python manage.py runserver
> d:\django\firmy\ogloszenia\models.py(5)<module>()
-> class Kategoria(models.Model):
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\firmy\ogloszenia\models.py(25)<module>()
-> class Firma(models.Model):
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> d:\django\firmy\ogloszenia\models.py(25)<module>()->None
-> class Firma(models.Model):
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(219)_call_with_frames_removed()->None
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(678)exec_module()->None
(Pdb) n
--Call--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(318)__exit__()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(319)__exit__()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(320)__exit__()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(321)__exit__()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(327)__exit__()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(329)__exit__()
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(329)__exit__()->None
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(670)_load_unlocked()
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(670)_load_unlocked()-><module 'oglo...a\\models.py'>
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(956)_find_and_load_unlocked()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(958)_find_and_load_unlocked()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(959)_find_and_load_unlocked()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(960)_find_and_load_unlocked()
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(960)_find_and_load_unlocked()-><module 'oglo...a\\models.py'>
(Pdb) n
--Call--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(151)__exit__()
(Pdb) n
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(152)__exit__()
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(152)__exit__()->None
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(971)_find_and_load()-><module 'oglo...a\\models.py'>
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(994)_gcd_import()-><module 'oglo...a\\models.py'>
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py(126)import_module()-><module 'oglo...a\\models.py'>
-> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py(198)import_models()->None
-> self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(111)populate()
-> for app_config in self.app_configs.values():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(114)populate()
-> self.clear_cache()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(116)populate()
-> self.models_ready = True
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(119)populate()
-> for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(120)populate()
-> app_config.ready()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(119)populate()
-> for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(120)populate()
-> app_config.ready()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(119)populate()
-> for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(120)populate()
-> app_config.ready()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(119)populate()
-> for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(120)populate()
-> app_config.ready()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(119)populate()
-> for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(120)populate()
-> app_config.ready()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(119)populate()
-> for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(120)populate()
-> app_config.ready()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(119)populate()
-> for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(120)populate()
-> app_config.ready()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(119)populate()
-> for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(122)populate()
-> self.ready = True
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py(122)populate()->None
-> self.ready = True
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py(24)setup()->None
-> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py(225)wrapper()->None
-> fn(*args, **kwargs)
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py(349)execute()
-> self.autocomplete()
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py(351)execute()
-> if subcommand == 'help':
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py(360)execute()
-> elif subcommand == 'version' or self.argv[1:] == ['--version']:
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py(362)execute()
-> elif self.argv[1:] in (['--help'], ['-h']):
(Pdb) n
> d:\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py(365)execute()
-> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have no circular category relations where one category is its own (distant) ancestor? That would make those `while` loops infinite.

Comment: Really I dont know. I want to use a like in this article https://djangopy.org/how-to/how-to-implement-categories-in-django/

Comment: while the admin panel is hanging, is there any message in the console?

Comment: Either start the debugger of your IDE and set some break points or add some debug print/log statements so can see what's going on in the console.

Comment: No, nothing. It looks like in the problem in while. In console still waiting to get the address

Comment: I edited my question when I use debugger